# AngularJS Form Validation Directive $setValidity on element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use `$setValidity` on an element in a directive.  All the examples I've found seem to set it on the controller...

I forked a JS fiddle on Form Validation and have tried a bunch of things.  Any insights would be most appreciated:
http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/pmKpG/2/

In the fiddle, the `$setValidity` is called on the controller:

```
ctrl.$setValidity('pwd', true);
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
elm.$setValidity('pwd', true);
```

so that in the form I can do something like:

```
ng-class="{error:form.password.$error.pwd}"
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I figured it out... You have to have a name on the input elements.  As soon as I added the name, the errors were automatically bound to the elements as desired, no additional changes needed!

```
<input ng-model="password"
       name="inputPassword"
       class="immediate-help"
       password-validate
       required
       type="password"
       id="inputPassword"
       placeholder="Password">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/pmKpG/4/

Comment: @Thom Porter, Why do you return undefined instead of false line 22  (http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/pmKpG/4/) ?

Comment: Plus one for answering your own question - and sharing with others

Comment: @thom-porter, what is the significance of the name "pwd" in your $setValidity call? It makes no difference what I change that value to...