# angularjs: access form field inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-form

I have a directive barFoo that has the following template:

```
<div>
    ....
    <input ng-model="data">
</div>
```

This directive is used inside a form! Now, inside this directive I want to do things like

```
element.find('input').$setValidity('bar-valid', false);
```

However, this doesn't work. Also the input field doesn't have a **name** attribute.
Is there any way to do this without a 'name' attribute ?

UPDATE: An other solution is to define ngModel on the directive element

```
<bar-foo ng-model="data.value"></bar-foo>
```

And rewrite the directive as follows

```
....
    .directive('barFoo', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            ...
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('bar-valid', false);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [AngularJS Form Validation Directive $setValidity on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615071/angularjs-form-validation-directive-setvalidity-on-element)

I will give you exactly what you need including code

Comment: The solution in that post is to use the **name** attribute. In this question I'm wondering if it is possible to do it without

Comment: $serValidity is part of the angularjs magic. If you want to use it, than you need to stick to angularjs Form handling. And this means, you need a name attribute. What is the problem with the name attribute anyway?

Comment: Well, the directive is generic. Inside one form it can be used multiple times. So if I need to use the **name** attribute I need to generate a random name (I think). So thats why I was wondering if I could do without

Comment: you will still have to user the name attribute.. only thing is: you will have to use ng-form inside your directive

Answer (score 1):

You can call a directive with name="itAmazingName" and use it in directive template, that should solve your problems

Comment: This cannot work. If you have multiple elements with **name="itAmazingName"**, I would say that the $setValidity breaks, because the form treats all the elements as one entity!

Comment: Who said about multiple elements with same name? I only suggested to use name for directive and then consume it in directive template

Comment: Ok, you want to call the directive element with a name attribute. Interesting, but still you have to generate a name attribute value.