# How do I reset the $invalid flag on all form element in Angular

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am new to Angular and I'm trying to implement an ASP.Net data annotations error handling service.  Everything is working great, except that I can't seem to reset the $invalid flag on the form when the form is re-submitted.

In my service, I'm doing:

```
app.service("submitFormSvc", ['$http', '$parse', function ($http, $parse) {
    this.submitForm = function (url, form, $scope) {
       form.$setPristine();

        ... More code here ...
       // Set individual form fields if an error is returned from the server
       $parse(form.$name + '.' + dotNetFieldName + '.$invalid').assign($scope, true);
    }
});
```

and my controller:

```
$scope.login = function () {
    submitFormSvc.submitForm('/api/login', $scope.loginForm, $scope)
}
```

I was under the impression that the $setPristine() would reset all the values on the form, but it isn't.

Do I need to loop through all form variables and reset them individually?  If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Did you look at this SO post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603914/reset-form-to-pristine-state-angularjs-1-0-x

Comment: Also what version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.2.2.  I figured out that $setPristine only affect the $dirty flag, and this is actually working perfectly.  I'm looking for the sister method that will reset the $invalid flag.  I would assume that $setValidity on the form would do this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure about your code involving $setValidity, but did you check out SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615071/angularjs-form-validation-directive-setvalidity-on-element  ?